# AWK - add value based on regex

Tags: regex, linux, awk

I have to add the numbers returned by REGEX using awk in linux.

Basically from this file:

```
123john456:x:98:98::/home/john123:/bin/bash
```

I have to add the numbers `123` and `456` using awk.
So the result would be `579`

So far I have done the following:

`awk -F ':' '$1 ~ VAR+="/[0-9].*(?=:)/" ; {print VAR}' /etc/passwd`

`awk -F ':' 'VAR+="/[0-9].*(?=:)/" ; {print VAR}' /etc/passwd`

`awk -F ':' 'match($1, VAR=/[0-9].*?:/) ; {print VAR}' /etc/passwd`

And from what I've seen match doesn't support this at all.

Does someone has any idea?

UPDATE:
it also should work for
`john123` result - > `123`
`123john` result - > `123`

Comment: You're trying to use a PCRE regexp in a tool that supports EREs.

Comment: See `awk -F ':' '{n=split($1, a, /[^0-9]+/); b=0; for (i=1;i<=n;i++) { b += a[i]; }; print b; }' /etc/passwd` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55621032/3832970)

Comment: So, can there be an arbitrary amount of numbers?

Comment: Just wondering, but what is the use of this?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F':' '{split($1,t,/[^0-9]+/); print t[1] + t[2]}' file
579
```

With your updated requirements:

```
$ cat file
123john456:x:98:98::/home/john123:/bin/bash
john123:x:98:98::/home/john123:/bin/bash
123john:x:98:98::/home/john123:/bin/bash

$ awk -F':' '{split($1,t,/[^0-9]+/); print t[1] + t[2]}' file
579
123
123
```

Answer (score 0):

With gawk and for the given example

```
awk -F ':' '{a=gensub(/[a-zA-Z]+/,"+", "g", $1); print a}' inputFile | bc
```

would do the job.
More general:

```
awk -F ':' '{a=gensub(/[a-zA-Z]+/,"+", "g", $1); a=gensub(/^+/,"","g",a); a=gensub(/+$/,"","g",a); print a}' inputFile | bc
```

The regex-part replaces all sequences of letters with '+' (e.g., '`12johnny34`' becomes `12+34`). Finally, this mathematical operation is evaluated by `bc`.
(The be safe, I remove leading and trailing '+' sings by `^+` and `+$`)

Comment: Please add space after the -F option, besides this, running the command will return an error for each line `(standard_in) 1: syntax error`

Comment: Yeah, it seems that it works with a regular file, not the passwd one. I guess it's a permissions issue. Could you please give me a short summary on how that works?

Comment: You should mention that's gawk-only for gensub() (maybe some versions of mawk too). @JohnnyOnPc - you do NOT get a syntax error when running a script with some input files but not others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[^0-9]+` as a field separator, and `:[^\n]*\n` as a record separator instead:

```
awk -F '[^0-9]+' 'BEGIN{RS=":[^\n]*\n"}{print $1+$2}' /etc/passwd
```

so that given the content of /etc/passwd being:

```
123john456:x:98:98::/home/john123:/bin/bash
john123:x:98:98::/home/john123:/bin/bash
123john:x:98:98::/home/john123:/bin/bash
```

This outputs:

```
579
123
123
```

Comment: This only works when there is a number in front and afterwards the username as '123john312', doesn't work for cases when the username doesn't contain any number. Or when it has a number afterwards only or before only, etc. Thank you for your answer thou.

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for multi-char RS.

Answer (score 0):

I used awk's `split()` to separate the first field on any string not containing numbers.

`split(string, target_array, [regex], [separator_array]*)`

**separator_array requires gawk*

```
$ awk -F: '{split($1, A, /[^0-9]+/, S); print S[1], A[1]+A[2]}' <<EOF
123john456:x:98:98::/home/john123:/bin/bash
123john:x:98:98::/home/john123:/bin/bash
EOF

john 579
john 123
```

Comment: @EdMorton, Good catch. The one time I don't run it through `original-awk` and I get called out by the fastest awk in the west.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
awk -F ':' '{n=split($1, a, /[^0-9]+/); b=0; for (i=1;i<=n;i++) { b += a[i]; }; print b; }' /etc/passwd
```

See [online `awk` demo](https://ideone.com/Re9LjU)

```
s="123john456:x:98:98::/home/john123:/bin/bash
john123:x:98:98::/home/john123:/bin/bash"
awk -F ':' '{n=split($1, a, /[^0-9]+/); b=0; for (i=1;i<=n;i++) { b += a[i]; }; print b; }' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
579
123
```

**Details**

- `-F ':'`  - records are split into fields with `:` char
- `n=split($1, a, /[^0-9]+/)` - gets Field 1 and splits into digit only chunks saving the numbers in `a` array and the `n` var contains the number of these chunks
- `b=0` - `b` will hold the sum
- `for (i=1;i<=n;i++) { b += a[i]; }` - iterate over `a` array and sum the values
- `print b` - prints the result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another `awk` variant that adds *all the numbers* present in first field separated by `:`:

```
cat file
123john456:x:98:98::/home/john123:/bin/bash
john123:x:98:98::/home/john123:/bin/bash
123john:x:98:98::/home/john123:/bin/bash
1j2o3h4n5:x:98:98::/home/john123:/bin/bash

awk -F '[^0-9:]+' '{s=0; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {s+=$i; if ($i~/:$/) break} print s}' file
```

```
579
123
123
15
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try Perl also

```
$ cat johnny.txt
123john456:x:98:98::/home/john123:/bin/bash
john123:x:98:98::/home/john123:/bin/bash
123john:x:98:98::/home/john123:/bin/bash

$ perl -F: -lane ' $_=$F[0]; $sum+= $1 while(/(\d+)/g); print $sum; $sum=0 ' johnny.txt
579
123
123

$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '
123john456:x:98:98::/home/john123:/bin/bash
john123:x:98:98::/home/john123:/bin/bash
123john:x:98:98::/home/john123:/bin/bash
john:x:98:98::/home/john123:/bin/bash'    |
```

---

```
awk '($0 += $2)_' FS='[^0-9]+(:.+)?'
```

---

```
579
123
123
0
```

This runs on just about any `awk` you can find.